# Testing render_template with Rails 4

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

I have this working test on Rails 3.2

```
it('render messages') { expect(helper.error_message('test')).to render_template('message') }
```

However this dont works on Rails 4, this is the message:

```
  2) ApplicationHelper#error_message render messages
     Failure/Error: it('render messages') { expect(helper.error_message('test')).to render_template('message') }
       expecting <"message"> but rendering with <["_message"]>
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have searched for changes on ActionView that could affect this but didnt found anything. I wonder if the solution is just adding the `_`

```
expect(helper.error_message('test')).to render_template('_message')
```

Or is there any downside doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial, correct? Pass in the partial name to `render_template`:

```
render_template(:partial => "_message")
```

More info in the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)